# Eliminating C++ virtual functions when you can only downcast the base class to a sub class at runtime

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, traits, crtp

I am trying to remove virtual calls in some tight loops in C++... easy enough with CRTP or just templates in general, but obviously this requires the compiler to know the type at compile time.

In my program there are variously optimized implementations of lets say a BitSet, and the code that refers to that BitSet does so via a reference/pointer to the base class.

Now I happen to know (because my object graph is made of identified types) what sub class a particular BitSet reference is, so I can write a trivial "decoder" function that has a code path in which each BitSet type is cast to the real subclass.

I can then call a non virtual function on that type, which is great for one operation.

My problem is (my last use of C++ was about 10 years ago so I'm catching up), I have various algorithms with different inputs/outputs that make many calls to the bitset's virtual functions, so I'd like to make template versions of those algorithms, templated by actual BitSet subclass. (The alternative would be to copy the "decoder" function for every algorithm)

This requires me to pass the algorithm whether it be a templated function or a class, to the "decoder" function, and this is where I'm having trouble. I don't know what the type parameter for the BitSet is when I'm calling the decoder, and the compiler complains - If i could leave it unspecified in some way, the compiler should have all the info it needs to generate and call a specific implementation of the algorithm at each place where I have provided it with the concrete type in the "decoder" function

Comment: Please show C++ code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your decoder could have a template template parameter. I.e your decoder is templated on an algorithm class that is templated on the BitSet. The decoder then creates an instance of the algorithm class for the particular type of BitSet and executes it:

```
template<template<typename> typename Algorithm>
void decoder(BitSet& bitset) {
  switch(bitset.type()) {
    case 1:
      Algorithm<VectorBitSet>()(static_cast<VectorBitSet&>(bitset));
      break;
    case 2:
      Algorithm<ArrayBitSet>()(static_cast<ArrayBitSet&>(bitset));
      break;
    default:
      throw std::logic_error("Unknown BitSet type");
  }
}

template<typename T>
struct PrintAlgorithm {
  void operator()(const T& bitset) {
    std::cout << "Type: " << bitset.type() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Size: " << bitset.size() << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i != bitset.size(); ++i) {
      std::cout << bitset.at(i) << "\n";  // No virtual function call. 
    } 
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
};
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xYCpkqbHwvZWs3u2)

Comment: I don't see how replacing a virtual call with a switch can change performance being both jumps on a tabled address.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia The switch happens only once for the whole algorithm, the virtual function calls could happen potentially many times within an algorithm.

Comment: I got your point, but compiler optimization and processor pipe prediction will make the two  things substantially equivalent (if the indirect jump is constant within the loop, the compiler will cache the address out of it).

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia You are putting a lot of faith in the compiler and the processor. Of course this is something you would only do if you could measure a performance improvement. I am just showing how to do what OP asked and I'll leave it to them to measure.

Comment: Yes... There was an age I was not putting all of that faith. I I've been accused of "premature optimizations". Then I started to write compilers.

Comment: Thanks for the responses... yes I will be profiling... note the main target here is asm.js, so even a known jump may be costly. Also I have cases which are more complex (different types of int lookups) where it is a chain of virtual function calls that I'd like to eliminate. Finally, doing things this way gives the compiler a chance to inline the at() in the particular algorithm instantiation

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of steps I'd take:

- First thing is of course setting up benchmarks and a profiler. Without knowing how much you improved, it's impossible to tell whether some change was good or not.
- Then, I'd consider removing all virtual stuff from the bitset class, so you have distinct concrete implementations that just have the same interface but are not derived from a baseclass. This makes it impossible to waste time in virtual function lookups.
- As replacement, you could provide various decorators that you can wrap over the concrete bitset classes to make them polymorphic at runtime. This allows you to still use existing code that requires a polygorphic bitset type.
- Lastly, with the help of benchmarks and the profiler, you could convert some of the functions that still take a polymorphic bitset to function templates, so you can pass the concrete bitset types as parameters. Doing this, you avoid the runtime overhead of virtual function calls for these specific function calls.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are essentially trying the impossible: if the actual type of the parameter is not known at COMPILE TIME, you have in any case to check the type an call a different function (weather it has a different name or a same name with different template parameter does not change what the processor has to do). The fact the check happens implicitly (via v-table) or explicitly (via a case or a if-else if ... or by means of an array of function pointers :-O ) does not change the number of operation the processor has to do.  You are removing v-tables and reinventing them into your own code. Quite hard that it will change something on performance.